# Nginx backend shutdown without losing sessions

Tags: shutdown, nginx

So I'm having reverse proxy server, where Nginx working as proxy server and loadbalancer. My biggest problem, that I have 2 app backends, which I need sometimes to shutdown. When I write after server ***down*** the backend, shutdown and looses sessions. How can I gracefully shutdown one of my app server? So that Nginx wait while all sessions will be completed or for some time? Thank for help.

My simple config:

```
upstream loadbalancer {
                ip_hash;
                server          192.168.0.1:443;
                server          192.168.0.2:443;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need store the Session somewhere both of servers can read.
This can be done by several methods, like, a Database or a MemCached server.
Some of most usually Php Framework has this functionality out of the box, like Yii Framework.